# Getting bundler: failed to load command: shoryuken (/usr/local/bundle/bin/shoryuken)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, shoryuken

I'm getting below error in my QA logs

`bundler: failed to load command: shoryuken (/usr/local/bundle/bin/shoryuken)`

Below is my setup information.

Ruby version: ruby 3.0.3p15
Rails version: Rails 7.0.3

Bundler version: Bundler version 2.3.6
Shoryuken version: Shoryuken version 6 is installed during bundle install
I used gem 'shoryuken' in Gemfile

Also we are using AWS SQS!

Previously I got the below error

`Error occurred while trying to configure Shoryuken : uninitialized constant ShoryukenCustomRegistry`

This error got fixed after I added a required ShoryukenCustomRegistry line in my shoryuken.rb file.

however now I can see bundler error as below in qa logs.

`bundler: failed to load command: shoryuken (/usr/local/bundle/bin/shoryuken)`

Please tell me possible reasons or solutions for this, thanks in advance.